# How to disable autocomplete that was already enabled

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using a login page. That was autocomplete enabled, at that time it asks do you want to save the password  and some of the username and passwords are saved. Now I want to disable the autocomplete, the problem it is not asking do you want to save  password but the already saved usernames are shown on the field. Is there any was to disable that without clearing cache?

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho i just tried only autocomplete="false"